# Does Julia's column-major order have any impact while calling CVXPY through PyCall?

Tags: julia, cvxpy, pycall

I'm using `CVXPY` through Julia, a language where multidimentional arrays are stored in memory using column-major order. However `CVXPY` is written in Python and accepts `Numpy` style arrays (which are row-major by default) to be used as constants.

I want to know if I should care about ordering, e.g. with matrix `A`, when translating Python code like this:

```py
import cvxpy as cp
import numpy as np

m = 30
n = 20

A = np.random.randn(m, n)
b = np.random.randn(m)

# Construct the problem.
x = cp.Variable(n)
objective = cp.Minimize(cp.sum_squares(A*x - b))
constraints = [0 <= x, x <= 1]
prob = cp.Problem(objective, constraints)
```

to Julia:

```
using Random, PyCall
cp = pyimport("cvxpy")

m = 30
n = 20

A = randn(m, n)
b = randn(m)

# Construct the problem.
x = cp.Variable(n)
objective = cp.Minimize(cp.sum_squares(cp.matmul(A,x) - b))
constraints = [0 <= x, x <= 1]
prob = cp.Problem(objective, constraints)
```

Comment: Looks like a valid question, but imho real-world applications of cvxpy and it's solvers are not dense and therefore lots of things change as sparse-matrices are not numpy-based anymore and there is a need for copying for sure (i suppose), as things get much more complex: not only col-major vs. row-major anymore. Another remark: i guess that everything your might lose due to copying (or whatever happens during wrapper) is dominated by solver-time.Fun fact: probably every solver there is will again copy and reorder your input to it's own internal matrix-format (see cvxopt, ecos, ...).

Answer (score 0):

I've seen exactly this done, and not seen any special handling from want I recall.
So no, it doesn't cause any issues